# Quicktime object doesn't change width or height

Tags: html, object, quicktime

I'm editing an existing set up where an audio QuickTime object is being used and embedded into the page. Whenever I adjust the width or height of the object, the actual controls and the background image don't change, they just stay the same size and center themselves in the new height and width defined.

Here is my code:

```
<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" height="256" width="472">

    <param name="src" value="PATH-TO-AUDIO-M4A">
    <param name="autoplay" value="false">
    <param value="false">
    <embed bgcolor='##000000' src="PATH-TO-AUDIO-M4A" height="100%" width="472" autoplay="false" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">

</object>
```

I want the width of the object to be 472px, but it just centers inside that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `scale="tofit"` property -

```
<object
classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"
codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab"
height="136"
width="472" >
<param name="src" value="sample.mov"/>
<param name="scale" value="tofit" />
<param name="controller" value="true" /> 
<param name="autoplay" value="false" />
<embed type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
height="136" width="472" src="sample.mov" scale="tofit" controller="true" autoplay="false" />
</object>
```

scale is an optional value that will scale the media display according to the height and width specified multiplied by the value given. The default value is 1 (i.e. 1x). If you used a 2, the display would be twice as big as the height and width specified (i.e. 2x). You can also use the values "tofit" and "aspect". "tofit" will stretch or compress (change the apsect of) the movie to fit the height and width specified. "aspect" will fit the movie as closely as possible to the height and width specified without changing its aspect ratio.